indent python files with only 2 chars on linux
I have this project where python files are indented with 2 chars, not 4.
On my mac, I use macvim (VIM - Vi IMproved 9.1 (2024 Jan 02, compilé Jan  4 2024 03:08:50)). When I edit a file like this:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# vim: se ts=2 sw=2 et ai mouse=:

Everything is ok. Vim does not try to indent code for me. When I hit TAB, vim adds 2 spaces. I have to press BACKSPACE twice to unindent. That's something I'm used to and the behavior I'm looking for. Example:
def foo():
#<- the cursor stays at column 0. 
  # Pressing TAB adds 2 chars
# I have to press BACKSPACE twice to get back at column 0.

Now, on "Raspbian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)" GNU/Linux, with vim-nox (VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compilé May 04 2023 10:24:44))
modelines are activated too, but the effect with the same modeline is not quite the same.
def foo():
  #<- cursor automatically at postition 2, strange for me but acceptable
      # but now TAB adds 4 chars and
  # pressing BACKSPACE once removes 4 chars

Some default configuration is at work here and tries to help me. Unfortunately, my fingers have been used to the first, more basic behavior for decades, that this help is in fact counterproductive.
more info vim packages:
ii  vim-common       2:9.0.1378-2          all Vi IMp
ii  vim-nox          2:9.0.1378-2          armhf Vi I
ii  vim-runtime      2:9.0.1378-2          all Vi IMp
ii  vim-tiny         2:9.0.1378-2          armhf Vi I

file /etc/vim/vimrc.local
" always load defaults early
source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim
" prevent vim to reload defaults and so override the settings we make here
let g:skip_defaults_vim = 1
se background=dark
se ai modeline modelines=5 ruler showmatch showmode noic
se scrolloff=0
"
" Don't let vim use the mouse.
if has('mouse')
  set mouse=
endif
if exists('+incsearch')
  set noincsearch
endif
if has('syntax')
  syntax on
endif
" Tente de désactiver les autoindentations "malines"
se indentexpr= nocindent nosmartindent
" un ruler avec les positions des caractères (offset + 1) en decimal et hexa
se rulerformat=%30(%7o:%-5O%=%l,%c%V%=%P%)

No ~/.exrc, ~/.vimrc, ~/.vim/vimrc, /home/me/project/.vimrc, /home/me/project/.exrc.
The question:
How do I, at least, persuade this helping module to use 2 chars not 4 or even better, deactivate it completely ?

Can you update the "broken" one (if so, does that fix it)? See also How to debug my vimrc and try :verbose setlocal ts? sw? sts? et? ai? formatoptions? indentexpr? indentkeys?

My system is up to date. and this is the vim version that comes with Debian/raspbian. So I'd say i can't upgrade to 9.1.

@D.BenKnoble, Thank you for the "how to debug" pointer. I'll check that and update the question.

First things first: establish a baseline with $ /path/to/vim filename +set\ modeline in both environments.

Why don't you use a ftplugin file in $HOME/.vim/ftplugin with proper options?

@simzz, Maybe because I haven't heard of those things until now ;-). A new world just opened and it'll take time until I correctly understand the whole thing. For now, simply adding:filetype indent off and filetype plugin indent off in my ~/.vimrc did it! This auto indent functionality that i'm not used to is disabled.

As suggested by @simzz, some filetype something was overriding my basic settings. I disabled both filetype and filetype plugin in my ~/.vimrc. Now only basic, non smart, autoindent is used, which is enough to make my fingers and the editor compatible again.
filetype indent off
filetype plugin indent off


The se doesn't correspond to any Vim 9.1 option.
I would remove the se part of the modeline and do:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# vim: ts=2 sw=2 et ai mouse=:


And I would add fileencoding=utf-8 because it's supposed to go on the first or second line.

thanks for the answer, but I already use the modeline line and it doesn't work as expected.

@Friedrich, I sure could add fileencoding but I don't experience encoding problems. So that seems pointless. thanks anyway.

Did you noticed the small change in the modeline I have removed the se part that is an unknown option (at least in Vim 9.1).?

@Vivian may I respectfully suggest that some explanation in addition to "I would do" would do a good job of hinting to the subtle changes you introduced?

Thanks @Friedrich :-) I have made an attempt to make my intention a bit less cryptic.

@exore my comment wasn't aimed at solving your problem but having standard-compliant and portable Python source code. Of course, the right place to start would be to use four spaces of indentation. I realize I was barking up the wrong tree.

@Friedrich, your opinion on the number of spaces is just an opinion, it's not helpful in any way. Let me quote PEP 8 that you linked Many projects have their own coding style guidelines. In the event of any conflicts, such project-specific guides take precedence for that project.

Let's try and keep the comments on-topic, folks.

@VivianDeSmedt, «The se doesn't correspond to any Vim 9.1 option». Indeed, because that's not an option. That's the abbreviation of the set command. See https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#modeline . the modeline as it is, is a perfectly valid modeline. The form you suggest, with no se command, traditionally does not end in :, although vim accepts it and happily deals with an empty implicit set command.

@exore Thanks for your feedback. I didn't knew. To analyze your problem further can you tell us what is the result of the following commands :verbose setlocal ts? :verbose setlocal ai? :verbose setlocal sw? :verbose setlocal et??

(You can put all the :verbose setlocal together; see https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/45174/indent-python-files-with-only-2-chars-on-linux#comment82241_45174 which I think we're still waiting on.)
